# No COM port detected when I plug in my USB Cable into my laptop

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I use Arduino IDE and the Arduino UNO X board. When I plug my USB cable into the USB port, the COM port doesn't show up under the Tools > Port shortcut, making me unable to upload my code. I tried downloading the CH340 driver, but it did nothing :( It has always worked before, but it suddenly won't work all of the sudden. I am using a Windows PC, it is does not show up under Device Manager > USB Serial Port Connection either. It works for other devices though.

Comment: Look [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/60013/79950) and [here](https://electronics-project-hub.com/arduino-not-detected-and-driver-issues-solved/) for some good suggestions.

Comment: have you installed the arduino drivers? first of all you need to do that

Comment: I found the solution in this link :
https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17/avrdude-stk500-getsync-not-in-sync-resp-0x00-aka-some-dude-named-avr-won?newreg=68429bc494514e9980e4a2dfb780fa62

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and I turned out to be using a power only USB cable rather than a data cable. Replacing the cable with a data cable solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

This problem can occur due to two main reasons.

1. Your computer does not recognize your Arduino board
2. Your Arduino Board is damaged

Sometimes your computer does not recognize your arduino board. You can check it by opening **Device Manager > Other Devices** If a device named Arduino Uno is there, probably it is due to the driver issue.
You can solve it by manually downloading the driver [from here.](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/DriverInstallation/)

If the Arduino Board is still not recognized, it can be due to a damaged cable or the Arduino board is damaged. Try using a different cable to connect it to your computer. If the board is still not recognized, the Arduino board might be damaged, You may have to repair the damaged board by giving it to a shop or may have to buy a new board which seems the easier way.